# How to compare two arrays and show matches in columns

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I have two arrays.

Array 1 - List of all dates
Array 2 - list of all dates a person is present

I want to show a table that has all the dates in the first row and at each day that a person is present on the second row, the respective column should say present.

I tried nested loop but it just shows various rows and one result per row i.e. only one match per row.

I want to accomplish something like this

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="6%">160111</td>
    <td width="6%">160113</td>
    <td width="6%">160120</td>
    <td width="6%">160127</td>
    <td width="6%">160201</td>
    <td width="6%">160203</td>
    <td width="6%">160208</td>
    <td width="6%">160210</td>
    <td width="6%">160217</td>
    <td width="6%">160224</td>
    <td width="6%">160229</td>
    <td width="6%">160302</td>
    <td width="6%">160307</td>
    <td width="6%">160309</td>
    <td width="6%">160321</td>
    <td width="5%">160323</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Present</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Present</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Present</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Suggestions? How to run loop or how can this be achieved?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your 2 arrays? What is the structure of the arrays?

Comment: @Sean Array 1 - 160129,160130 ; Array 2- 160129;

Comment: Loop through Array 1, and use `in_array()` to test if the value is in Array 2. If it is, display `present`.

Comment: @Arihant You state in your question `Array 2 list of all dates a person is present`, but then your example in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193161/how-to-compare-2-arrays-and-show-matches-in-columns#comment60020801_36193161) is `Array 2- 160129;`?? I don't see any dates in that array example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `in_array()` to test whether an item is in Array 2.

```
foreach ($array1 as $day) {
    echo "<td>";
    echo in_array($day, $array2) ? "Present" : "&nbsp;";
    echo "</td>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if Array are same like I given in my answer

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
    $dates =array(
        '160111','160113','160120','160127','160201','160203',
        '160208','160210','160217','160224','160229','160302',
        '160307','160309','160321','160323'  
    );
    $person_present =array(
        '','','','160127','','',
        '','160210','','','','160302',
        '','','',''  
    );

   foreach ($dates as $pkey => $day) 
   {
        if ( in_array($day, $person_present) ) {
            ?>
            <td>Present</td>
           <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
           <?php
        }        
   }
?>
```

**Full Code:**

```
    <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
      <tr>
        <td width="6%">160111</td>
        <td width="6%">160113</td>
        <td width="6%">160120</td>
        <td width="6%">160127</td>
        <td width="6%">160201</td>
        <td width="6%">160203</td>
        <td width="6%">160208</td>
        <td width="6%">160210</td>
        <td width="6%">160217</td>
        <td width="6%">160224</td>
        <td width="6%">160229</td>
        <td width="6%">160302</td>
        <td width="6%">160307</td>
        <td width="6%">160309</td>
        <td width="6%">160321</td>
        <td width="5%">160323</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
 <?php
    $dates =array(
        '160111','160113','160120','160127','160201','160203',
        '160208','160210','160217','160224','160229','160302',
        '160307','160309','160321','160323'  
    );
    $person_present =array(
        '','','','160127','','',
        '','160210','','','','160302',
        '','','',''  
    );

   foreach ($dates as $pkey => $day) 
   {
        if ( in_array($day, $person_present) ) {
            ?>
            <td>Present</td>
           <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
           <?php
        }        
   }
?>   
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate through Array1 ( foreach loop )
2. Check each value against Array2 ( **in_array()** )

Eg:-

```
echo "<br/><table border='1' style='width:100%'><tr><td>";
foreach($arr1 as $a1) {
echo "<table border='1' style='display:inline;border:0px solid'>";
echo "<tr><td>$a1</td></tr>";
    if(in_array($a1,$arr2)) {
        echo "<tr><td>Present</td></tr>";
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td> </td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
echo "</td></tr></table>";
```